# how to store array count in nsuserdefault

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, long-integer

How to Store long value in nsuserdefault

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[Arrayvalue count] forKey:@"ArrayCountNumber"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

or i am already tried to store [Arrayvalue count] into long value and like this

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:longvalue forKey:@"ArrayCountNumber"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Nothing worked...

Advance Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `NSUserDefaults` expects an `object` type and you should wrap you scalar type to `NSNumber` object:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@([Arrayvalue count]) forKey:@"ArrayCountNumber"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To retrieve value back use the following:

```
NSInteger count = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ArrayCountNumber"] integerValue];
```

Comment: how to check that in if else condition if ([Arrayvalue count] == [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ArrayCountNumber"])

Comment: Check the second part of answer: you need `integerValue` method call after `objectForKey`

Comment: I am use that too... but missed integervalue... thanks you so much... :) Why objectforkey not valueForKey...????